# Não consigo utilizar uma variável de uma classe em outra

Tags: java, variáveis, getters-setters, public

Estou com dificuldade pra utilizar uma variável de uma outra classe (não é a principal) em uma outra classe. Tenho que fazer um cálculo utilizando a variável **convidados** da classe *Festa* na classe Local. Já tentei deixar a variável public, já tentei construtores mas não consigo nada.

PS: ignorem o código feio. É meu primeiro trabalho da disciplina de Programação Orientada a Objetos.

Classe Festa

```
package principal;

public class Festa {

    private String cpf;
    public int convidados;
    private double custo;
    public String tipoFesta;

    public Festa(String cpf1, int convidados1, double custo1) {
        this.cpf = cpf1;
        this.convidados = convidados1;
        this.custo = custo1;
    }
        
    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }
    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }
    public int getConvidados() {
        return convidados;
    }
    public void setConvidados(int convidados) {
        this.convidados = convidados;
    }
    
    public double getCusto() {
        return custo;
    }
    public void setCusto(double custo) {
        this.custo = custo;
    }
    
    //métodos
    String mostraCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }
    
    int mostraConvidados(){
        return convidados;
    }
    
    double mostraCusto() {
        return custo;
    }
    
    public String classificaFesta() {
        if(convidados<300 && custo<15000) {
            tipoFesta = "Festa junina";
        } else {
            if(convidados<300 && custo>=15000) {
                tipoFesta = "Aniversário";
            } else {
                if(custo<15000) {
                    tipoFesta = "Formatura";
                } else {
                    tipoFesta = "Casamento";
                }
            }
        }
        return tipoFesta;
    }
}
```

Classe Local

```
package principal;

public class Local {

    private double largura;
    private double comprimento;
    private int qtdeConv;
    
    public Local(double largura, double comprimento) {
        this.largura = largura;
        this.comprimento = comprimento;
    }

    
    public double getLargura() {
        return largura;
    }

    public void setLargura(double largura) {
        this.largura = largura;
    }

    public double getComprimento() {
        return comprimento;
    }

    public void setComprimento(double comprimento) {
        this.comprimento = comprimento;
    }
    
    double mostraLargura(){
        return largura;
    }
    
    double mostraComprimento() {
        return comprimento;
    }
            
    public String possivelLocal() { //4 pessoas = 3m² -> proporção de 1.333...
        double tamanho = largura*comprimento;
        double proporcao = 4/3;
        
        
        
        double propConvidados = convidados/tamanho; // ..............
        String acomoda;
        
        if(propConvidados <= proporcao) {
            acomoda = "Sim";
        } else {
            acomoda = "Não";
        }
        return acomoda;
    }
    
    
}
```

Classe Principal

```
package principal;

public class Principal {

    public int convidadoscalculo;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Festa f1 = new Festa("123.456.789-10", 300, 15000);
        Local l1 = new Local(10,8);
        
        String cpf_1 = f1.getCpf();
        int qtde = f1.getConvidados();
        double valor = f1.getCusto();
        
        double larg = l1.getLargura();
        double comp = l1.getComprimento();
        
        String classificaFesta = f1.classificaFesta();
        
        System.out.println("CPF do contratante: "+cpf_1);
        System.out.println("Festa para "+qtde+" convidados.");
        System.out.println("Tendo um valor de "+valor+ " reais");
        System.out.println("Essa é uma festa de tipo: "+ classificaFesta +".");
        
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para que você possa usar a variável convidados na classe Local deves primeiro criar um construtor vazio na classe Festa `public Festa(){}` e depois, dentro da classe Local criar uma instância da classe Festa, assim: `Festa f = new Festa();`
Depois, na linha do cálculo faça `propConvidados = f.convidados/tamanho;`

Comment: Muito obrigado, Márcia! Deu certo aqui! :)

Answer (score 0):

essa dificuldade que você está enfrentando é muito conhecida e um modo de solucionar é aplicar a famosa injeção de dependência. Existem 3 tipos de Injeção de Dependência: injeção de construtor; injeção pelo setter e injeção de interface.

O mais usual é através de construtor, mas no seu caso vamos usar injeção pelo setter. Assim, vamos informar a classe Local quantos convidados existem através de um setter, e dessa forma, permitindo a classe Local trabalhar corretamente.

Para isso adicione o seguinte:

Classe local:

```
public void setQtdeConv(int qtdeConv){
    this.qtdeConv = qtdeConv;
}
```

Classe principal:

```
l1.setQtdeConv(f1.getConvidados());
```

Dessa forma, o objeto l1 agora possuí a quantidade de convidados que o objeto f1 têm, e conseguirá fazer o método possivelLocal().